# How to pass an object reference to a function with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several links which all use a similar function, so I want to call the function and pass it attributes from the object that made the call. How do I do this?

This is my code:

```
$('.flash').click(function(){
    getDimensions($(this));
    swfobject.embedSWF(fileRef, "myContent", fileWidth, fileHeight, "9.0.0");
});

function getDimensions(linkRef){
    fileHeight = $(linkRef).attr('data-height');
    fileWidth = $(linkRef).attr('data-width');
}
```

Am I just referencing `$(this)` improperly?

Comment: Aside from the fact that the two functions communicate using globals (bad!), what isn't working? It looks like it should work.

Comment: how would you write it without globals? I think that's my problem actually - I need that function to return the fileWidth and fileHeight and carry out the rest of the click function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('.flash').click(function(){
    var dimensions = getDimensions($(this));
    swfobject.embedSWF(fileRef, "myContent", dimensions.fileWidth, dimensions.fileHeight, "9.0.0");
});


function getDimensions(linkRef){
  return { 
    fileHeight: $(linkRef).attr('data-height'),
     fileWidth: $(linkRef).attr('data-width')
  }
}
```

Comment: @mheavers: did this work ? I don't think this will work because you are already passing a JQuery object to getDimensions and you are again wrapping it in another $() function. See my answer.

Comment: @euphoria83: This is totally fine to do in jQuery. If you pass a jQuery object to $() it simply returns the original set. $($(this)) == $(this);

Answer (score 1):

Without globals, you can return a JSON object:

```
$('.flash').click(function(){
   var d = getDimensions($(this));
   swfobject.embedSWF(fileRef, "myContent", d.width, d.height, "9.0.0"); }
);

function getDimensions(linkRef){
   return { "height" : $(linkRef).attr('data-height'),
            "width"  : $(linkRef).attr('data-width') }
}
```

Comment: This is very helpful. Can you explain why this is better than doing it the way paul alexander suggested?

Comment: @mheavers I think that is the same answer than paul alexander suggested, just posted almost at the same time ;)

Comment: @mheavers: Thinking a little bit about it maybe may version its clearer because "height" and "width" are the names of the attributes and not the names of some vars

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already passing a jQuery object to getDimensions function, you don't need to wrap the argument, linkRef, in another `$()` function inside the getDimensions function.

Use this instead:

```
function getDimensions(linkRef){
    fileHeight = linkRef.attr('data-height');
    fileWidth = linkRef.attr('data-width');
}
```

Comment: While it is true you don't need to re-wrap, it is totally fine to do so. If you pass a jQuery object to $() it simply returns the original set. $($(this)) == $(this); It is quite common to just wrap incoming parameters in $() to ensure that you're always dealing with a jQuery set.